# Symfony 4 doctrine, create automatically some entries when the doctrine:migrations:migrate is executed

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

In Symfony 4, I created some entities and when I generate tables via the command:

```
./bin/console doctrine:database:create && \
./bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff && \
./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

all works fine, my database is created with all tables/relations I defined from entities files.

My question is: When I create a new database and 'migrate' my entities files, how can I add automatically some entries in the newest database? Can I do that from entity file or repository file? I can run a simple arbitrary sql command after `./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` but I think there could be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Fixtures. I recommend using [Alice](https://github.com/nelmio/alice) and for generating testing/development fixtures Faker for this.

There is a popular bundle called [hautelook/AliceBundle](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle) which integrates both tools nicely into Symfony. This bundle also provides an additional command, which you can then use in your toolchain:

```
bin/console hautelook:fixtures:load
```